# Syntax highlight rule for a block comment using indentation

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting

I have the following code and I want to define a syntax highlight rule that will show all lines as commented out starting at the line with `##` till the indentation ends just before the last print line.

The indentation works like that in python.

```
function test a b
    arg Int a b
    ## if a>b
        show "Bigger"
        another command
    print "More stuff"
```

I think I should use something like the following, but how do I define the end condition based on indentation ? The start condition should somehow remember its indentation and the end condition should use that information. But how ?

```
syntax region myComment start=/\v##/ skip=/\v\\./ end=???
```

The comment highligthing should also stop when encountering a blank line.

```
function test a b
    arg Int a b
    ## if a>b
       show "Bigger"

function more a b
    arg Int a b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following:

```
syntax region Comment start=/^\z(\s*\)##/ end=/^\z1\ze\S/
```

See `:h /\z(\)`.

Basically it saves whitespace indentation in `\z1` and use it in `end` of region just before first non-whitespace. Also see `:h /\ze`.

[image]

**For Edited part of question**

Make it also end on empty line

```
syntax region Comment start=/^\z(\s*\)##/ end=/\(^\z1\ze\S\)\|\(^\s*$\)/
```

by adding empty line regex to the `end`.

[image]

Bear in mind that it probably wouldn't work if you mix tabs and spaces.

Comment: Thanks. It does solve my original question, but not my entire problem. When the commented block is followed by a blank line instead of another command, the highlighting breaks for the rest of the file. I will edit my question to show this case as well.

Comment: @PaulSchutte check updates

Comment: I'm sure it would work with tabs+space, because `\s` matches both. But in general best to avoid them, sure

Comment: But the length would be different for \z part